# Joda DateTimeFormatter print with minus signal

Tags: java, date, jodatime, date-formatting

I have a curious case that I came across this week. I have a specific class that has some code similar to this.

```java
public class DateHelper {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/ddHH:mm:ssZ");

    public String formateDate(DateTime dateTime) {
        return FORMATTER.print(dateTime).substring(0, 21);
    }
}
```

I have a batch process that write that formated date into a file.
The problem is, with aparently no reason, one DateTime object, loaded with Hibernate from a Oracle database with this value "03/08/16 19:56:50,000000000" are formatted into:

- "**-2015/07/1719:56:50+0**"

instead of

- "**2016/08/0319:56:50+00**"

More strange than that, is that I have three records on the database with that same time, and two of them are formatted correctly, the other one no.

I have a problem that this is occurring in a production server, because of this I don't have access to debug the code there. Making a dump of that records and testing locally, everything works fine (obviously)

Has Anyone ever had something similar with Joda-time? 
I use Java 1.6 with joda 2.4.

My only hope, that I have not tested yet, is update joda to their last version to check if it is some bug.

Comment: Perhaps the Oracle value `03/08/16 19:56:50,000000000` is not the year `2016` like you think it is. Try displaying the value with full year, e.g. `TO_CHAR(value, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`, or better yet `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM value)`

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help, i got a weird result. The first query return **03-AGO-2016 19:56:50**, while the second one using EXTRACT returned **-2016** I have no clue of what is this occurring but this is more than I had yesterday hahaha, I will dig more into this, thanks.